# Where should I place the cooler?

Tags: thermodynamics, temperature

Here is my problem,
There are two Rooms.
Room 1 that is my living room and Room 2 that is my bedroom.

What I want to achieve, throw all the heat from Room 2 to Room 1, with Room 2 being at higher temperature (warmer) and Room 1 being at lower temperature.

*Outside Temperature is lower than both of my room (Room 1 and Room 2)*

**Scenario 1**

So I have this cooler which I kept with vent facing to room 1.

Cooler works on the principle of evaporative cooling. So for this scenario, I have kept the pump on that means the water will flow through the honeycomb structure.

What I am assuming is that

-> the heat from the Room 2 will be used to cool my room 1 and the temperature of Room 1 will drop.

-> Meanwhile since the air of Room 2 is used that will create a low pressure and fresh air from outside will flow in if I keep the window open.

**Scenario 2**

Lets say that if I keep the vent facing to Room 2 and switch of the pump in cooler off that is no water will flow through the cooler and just using the cooler as a fan.

That means the air from Room 1 will be used to cool Room 2.

My assumption.

-> This would also cool my Room 2.

Which is the best way to cool both of my room?

Edit 1:

[image]

Layout

In the night, the outside temperature is lower compared to both Room, but since I live on top floor, the above slabs get heated and it starts radiating heat. I want to cool all my room.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like you want to transfer heat from Room 2 to Room 1, but you haven't mentioned the reason behind it. Are you trying to cool down Room 2 or warm up Room 1? Depending on the goal, the approach may vary.

In scenario 1, using the evaporative cooler with the vent facing Room 1 will result in the air in Room 1 being cooled down by the water flowing through the honeycomb structure. However, this may not be an efficient way to transfer heat from Room 2 to Room 1 as the cooler may not have enough cooling capacity to offset the heat generated in Room 2.

In scenario 2, using the cooler as a fan and facing the vent towards Room 2, will allow the air in Room 2 to circulate to Room 1, but again, it may not be an efficient way to transfer heat from Room 2 to Room 1. In this case, you may end up just circulating warm air from Room 2 to Room 1 without actually cooling Room 2.

There are other ways to transfer heat from one room to another, such as using a heat exchanger or a duct system. However, the best way to cool both of your rooms will depend on the specific conditions and layout of your house.

**Edit**

Based on the information you provided, one option that could be effective in cooling down both rooms to the outside temperature is to use a combination of natural ventilation, shading, and thermal insulation.

During the day, when the outside temperature is hotter than the inside of your home, you can close the windows and curtains or blinds on the sun-facing side of your home to keep the heat out. You can also use reflective film on the windows to reduce the amount of heat that enters your home.

At night, when the outside temperature is cooler than the inside of your home, you can open the windows and use fans to draw in the cool air and circulate it throughout your home. You can also use thermal insulation, such as ceiling insulation or insulation on the roof or walls, to prevent the heat from entering your home during the day and to keep the cool air in at night.

Additionally, you can consider using a portable air conditioner or evaporative cooler to cool down the air in the rooms where you spend the most time, such as your bedroom. However, it's important to note that air conditioners can be expensive to run and can contribute to high energy bills. So, using natural ventilation and shading during the day and relying on a portable cooler or fans at night may be a more cost-effective option.

Comment: Thanks, have updated the layout of the house.
The humidity outside is 49 percent, and outside temperature is 23 degree at night.

Since its is very hot during the day and I live on top floor, the slabs get heated, with my bedroom that is room 2 getting more hotter than my living room 1 that is Room .1.

I want both the room to have temperature equivalent to outside temperature.